# What are the chances of Energy Siphon appearing for a reward?

Tags: warframe

While doing research on Warframe, I realized there was an aura I would enjoy using much more than my corrosive projection, and it was Energy Siphon.  Much like other Auras, they are from Alerts. What are the chances that it will appear, and is there a specific time I should check the alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alerts are decided using Digital Extremes' custom-tailored Random Number Generator; the alerts are outside of DE's control, making the rewards entirely random. The one exception to this is the "Gift of the Lotus" missions provided at set dates, often playing host to an Orokin Catalyst or Orokin Reactor blueprint as a reward.

Technically speaking, the reward has a 1/x chance of being Energy Siphon, whereas X = the number of rewards possible in an alert mission.

If you wish to keep informed when there is an alert mission, you might try this helpful website: http://deathsnacks.com/wf/